# Hice este programa que acumula valores pero no da el resultado que debe

Tags: c, bucle-for

Este programa pide 5 valores y los acumula. al final los debería mostrar como resultado acumulado sumando los resultados pero no da la respuesta correcta. me podrían señalar mi error o si le falta algo? Aqui el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int v_acumulado;
    int v_leido;
    int c;
    for (c=1;c<=5;c++)
    {

        printf("Entre un valor: ");
        scanf("%d", &v_leido);
        v_acumulado= v_acumulado + v_leido;

    }
      printf("El total acumulado es .: %d", v_acumulado);
}
```

Comment: Debes inicializar tu variable v_acumulado en 0

Comment: int v_acumulado = 0; de esa manera en la declaracion

Comment: @Clinton Tapia Lagar Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes definir y asignar a cada variable un valor por defecto o tomara valores basuras que encuentra en memoria para cada variable haciendo que v_acumulado inicie con un dato que no es 0.

deberías colocarlo de esta forma :

```
int v_acumulado = 0, v_leido = 0;   
int c=1;
```

de esta manera le asignas el valor 0 a las dos primeras variables.